# Rvm broken inside screen

Tags: ruby, shell, rvm, gnu-screen

I'm using screen and even after rvm 1.9.2 and having an appropriate .rvmrc my server will *still* use jruby.
My .screenrc contains shell #{SHELL}
rvm info shows jruby.
It's as if rvm 1.9.2 doesn't have any effect, but it works fine outside screen.

Comment: I've discovered that the rvm function is not being loaded, but not sure why not. (tested with `type rvm | head -1`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I found a [solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/226783/how-to-tell-gnu-screen-to-run-bash-profile-in-each-new-window). Create a .screenrc file and put this snippet inside:

```
shell -$SHELL
```

The [official instructions](http://beginrescueend.com/workflow/screen/) omitted the dash.

Comment: `-$SHELL` didn't work for me, but `-${SHELL}` did. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making screen systematically use a login shell, you can source your  `~/.profile` file once the screen terminal is started.

It somehow promotes the shell started by screen to a login shell.

Answer (score -1):

`screen` might be replacing your PATH with something more restricted. Inside your screen session, do `echo $PATH`. It should show RVM's normal pre-pended sandbox in your home directory.

If it is truncating, you'll need to nose around in the docs OR... ask over on the SO peer sites [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) as this question is pretty off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's not truncated. It's just that rvm use 1.9.2 seems like a no-op.

Comment: I'd recommend emailing the author. His email is at `rvm -v`.